# How can I extract just the formatted date fields using sed or grep?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I need a grep or sed statement that would only take out the dates from this statement:

```
echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd'
```

So answer should be something like this:

```
12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12
```

I have gotten far enough to get `12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12`, but I cant remove the content between the dates. Is it possible to use a sed statement to keep the first word and last word using space to show which is the last word? The result should remain the same.

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/capturing-all-regex-matches-into-array.html

Answer (score 4):

#### Use POSIX Character Classes

A set of POSIX character classes would match your desired text. For example:

```
\b[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}\b
```

#### Sample Input/Output

The following pipeline will extract just the relevant text using GNU Grep, then concatenate the dates:

```
$ echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd' |
    grep -Eo '\b[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}\b' |
    xargs
12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 grep -o "[0-9]\{2\}-[^0-9]\{3\}-[^a-z]\{2\}" file | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd'  | sed 's: :\n:g' | grep ^[0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd' | sed 's/.*\(..-...-..\).*\(..-...-..\).*/\1 \2/'
12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12
```

To make the search pattern more specific for numbers and alphabets:

```
$ echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd' | sed 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]-[a-zA-Z]\{3\}-[0-9][0-9]\).*\([0-9][0-9]-[a-zA-Z]\{3\}-[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1 \2/'
12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12
```

Comment: what if there are more than two date's in the line?

Comment: @sarathi : I provide answer to what exactly OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
echo 'asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd' | sed 's/ /\n/g' |grep '-' | tr -d '\n' |sed 's/$/ \n/g'
```

output is

12-Dec-1311-Jan-12

Answer (score 0):

Try with awk

`awk '{for(i=1; i<NF; ++i){if ($i ~ /[0-9]+[-\w]*/) print $i}}' temp.txt`

Will work with any number of lines and columns

Comment: You should use `i<=NF` in case the `NF` field is a date.  Also, the OP may not want the dates return delimited( unclear from the question ).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '@a=/([\d]+-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[\d]+)/g;print "@a"'
```

tested:

```
> echo 'asdfdsfa 12-Dec-13 asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd' | perl -lne '@a=/([\d]+-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[\d]+)/g;print "@a"'
12-Dec-13 11-Jan-12
```

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting `date -d`. So it will even validate the date.

```
$ cat string 
asdfdsfa asdfs 12-Dec-13 asdasd asdf 11-Jan-12 asdasd

$ for i in `cat string`; do date -d $i &>/dev/null && echo $i; done
12-Dec-13
11-Jan-12
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'H;g;:a;s/\s*\n$//;t;s/\n(..-...-..)\b/\1 \n/;ta;s/\n([^0-9]+)/\n/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I had access logs where the dates where stupidly formatted : [30/Jun/2013:08:00:45 +0200]

but I needed to display it as : 30/Jun/2013 08:00:45

The problem is that using "OR" in my grep statement, I was receiving the 2 match expressions on 2 separated lines.

Here is the solution :

`grep -in myURL_of_interest  *access.log  | \
grep -Eo '(\b[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}\b)'   \
| paste - - -d" " > MyAccess.log`

I hope it helps :)