# Getting branch creation date from svn

Tags: bash, shell, svn, version-control

How do i can get creation date of a branch using shell commands.
I need only the full date (e.g 2010-06-20 13:05:57 ) that i will use in my script as a variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can grab the revision information containing this data using `svn log` with `--stop-on-copy` to omit anything before branch creation, and `--limit 1` to omit anything after. `--quiet` also helps, to remove the log message, since you're not interested in that:

```
svn log --limit 1 --stop-on-copy --revision 1:HEAD --quiet
```

This gives you a bunch of stuff in a string with the date, not the date by itself. To trim it, you need to pipe the output into another command. The answers to [How can I extract just the formatted date fields using sed or grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372305/how-can-i-extract-just-the-formatted-date-fields-using-sed-or-grep) show how you can use sed, grep, perl, or even the "date" command to accomplish this.